# Javascript window.open is blocked by IE popup blocker

Tags: javascript, popup

Can anyone help, I have a popup that is being blocked. It is a popup that is created because somebody has clicked on a Print picture on my site.

I thought IE is not supposed to block these when the popup came via an `onclick`?

Can anyone help? The `child1` variable is always returned as `NULL` if popup blocker enabled...

Maybe the problem is that the `onclick` event then passes control to a new function which loads a html file and does `child.document.write`

Here is my simple code..

```
var width = 800;
var height = 600;
var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth / 2) - (width / 2));
var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight / 2) - (height / 2));
var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height 
   + ",menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,left=" 
   + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;      

child1 = window.open("about:blank", "subWind", windowFeatures);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem will be that open will only return a reference to the window if you are navigating to somewhere within your current host.  You are navigating to about:blank which is not within your host.

Try adding a blank.htm file to your site and open that instead.  I'm still not sure that document.write will be allowed the document won't be open for write, you may be able to manipulate the DOM of the existing blank document though.

Comment: Yes thank you this was it, basically i need to load a file from my current web an d not BLANK ... so i created a empty html file .. loaded it in and used windows.write to write my html.. thank you and thanks for everyone elses comments

Answer (score 5):

The Internet Explorer pop-up blocker, when set to `Medium` filter level, will not block windows opened by JavaScript if they have been initiated by a user action. The following works fine in IE 6, 7 and 8:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin() {
    var width = 800;
    var height = 600;
    var left = Math.floor((screen.availWidth - width) / 2);
    var top = Math.floor((screen.availHeight - height) / 2);
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height +
            ",menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
            "left=" + left + ",top=" + top +
            "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;
    child1 = window.open("about:blank", "subWind", windowFeatures);
    writeTo(child1);
}
function writeTo(w) {
    w.document.write('Test');
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openWin();return false;">Test</a>
```

Note that using `document.write` into the newly opened window does not work in some web browsers. Also note that this may trigger a pop-up blocker in other browsers, even if it works as shown in Internet Explorer.

I have seen where invoking JavaScript from an `onclick` event can, in some cases, cause the pop-up blocker to trigger. It seems to have something to do with how *far* `window.open()` is from the onclick event. Too many levels of functions calling functions before you call `window.open()`. Without seeing your exact implementation, I can't tell you whether this is the problem you are having or not.

Answer (score 3):

It blocks it because it's not an anchor with a target="_blank". You're creating the popup programatically.

Just do this after the code example you've provided.

```
if (!child1) {
      alert('You have a popup blocker enabled. Please allow popups for www.yourSite.com');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try code

```
var newWin = window.open(...);
if (newWin && newWin.top) {
    // popup has opened
} else {
    // popup has been blocked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a dummy [form] with a target="_blank" instead of a window.open().

I hope it works.

Regards.

PD: I suppose adding your site to "trusted sites" is not an option, right?

Answer (score 0):

i have a idea in  ie 10/11 :

```
let win = window.open();
setTimeout(function(){
    win.customParam = 'xxxx';
});
```

in win ,you can get customParam after window onload with a timer or loop: