# window.open(....) getting blocked in some browsers

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I have a script where it opens a window for online application after executing some other scripts.

`window.open()` is not called on any click. It is getting called in a script and browser prevents the new window from appearing.

How to overcome this?

Here is the code:

```
window.open('/search/applyonline?jobid=".$jobDetails->getIdjob()."', 
            'applyurljob',
            'height=550,\ 
             width=800,\
             toolbar=no,\
             directories=no,\
             status=no,\
             menubar=no,\
             scrollbars=yes,\
             resizable=yes,\
             left=200,\
             top=250')
```

Comment: *How to over come this* Don't use `window.open`

Comment: ..Are you asking how to circumvent popup blockers?

Comment: Don't use window.open instead you can try [link](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example3/). This is having lot of options not like simple lightboxes

Comment: Can you use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888964/javascript-window-open-is-blocked-by-ie-popup-blocker)?

Comment: If I use blank for and submit it wont open in new window.

Comment: Btw, it looks like you're using some PHP code within your Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Popup blockers will block windows from being opened that are not in response to a click event. Therefore you can:

1. Ask your users to turn off their popup blocker (not nice).
2. Change your scripts to work in response to a link or button click.
3. Use fake windows such as a [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).