# How to open and then close a window without getting blocked as a popup?

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to direct a customer in an e-commerce site to pay via Paypal's website.
I would like the payment to be done in a new tab/window so the customer doesn't lose the current state of the web page he/she is at.

In order for the Paypal window to open without getting blocked, I am using an anchor with target="_blank". Which is working perfectly except for the fact, I can't close it after Paypal payment is done since `window.close()` doesn't work for windows that were not opened via `window.open()`.

How do I make it so it is BOTH not blocked as a popup AND I am able to close it with JS later on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888964/javascript-window-open-is-blocked-by-ie-popup-blocker  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616150/window-open-getting-blocked-in-some-browsers possible duplicate

Comment: Put the state information in the callback URL. Don't create a multiple window workflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139103/open-page-in-new-window-without-popup-blocking

lack of research.. possibly duplicate question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> In order for the Paypal window to open without getting blocked, I am using an anchor with target="_blank".

That's one option, but as long as you call `window.open` from within the handler for a user-generated event (like `click`), you can open pop-up windows. So just make sure you call `window.open` from within a `click` handler on the link (and then you can close it). Modern pop-up blockers (anything from the last several years) block pop-ups that aren't triggered by a user event, but allow ones that are.

```html
<p><a href="#" id="target">Click to open popup</a>; it will close automatically after five seconds.</p>
```

```js
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const wnd = window.open("https://stackoverflow.com");
    setTimeout(() => {
        wnd.close();
    }, 5000);
    return false;
});
```

*(Unfortunately, Stack Snippets don't let you do `window.open`.)*

Comment: what is the need for the timer here can you explain it more clearly

Comment: @VarunKumar: The `setTimeout` above is a placeholder for the asynchronous PayPal payment call.