# close a new pop up window in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using a form with submit button in html which opens a new window onclick of submit. Now i want this new window to be closed without user intervention.

i have tried below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin;
function newWindow()
{
    alert('in newWindow');
    newWin=window.open('http://someurl','_blank');
    setTimeout(function(){newWin.close()}, 10);
    alert('closed..');
}
</script>
```

but this does seem to close the new window. It still stays open. Pls help.

Comment: a full working code would help us help you...

Comment: 10ms timeout? wow ... quick window - perhaps too quick to see the popup blocker warning - check your developer tools console for errors

Comment: Does `'http://someurl'` have same origin as original `window`?

Comment: @guest271314 - shouldn't matter as the opener is the one closing it

Comment: Please check this link [Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702344/how-to-open-and-then-close-a-window-without-getting-blocked-as-a-popup)

Comment: @JaromandaX Trying to determine why approach at Question would not return expected result if popup blockers are not enabled.

Comment: @guest271314 - I understand - the code should (does) work - console output would help

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
      wnd.close();
    }, 5000); .Try

Comment: @guest271314 : its not the same domain. Its a totally different URL.

Comment: @JaromandaX: i initially tried with 30000, but then i dont need the user to even view it. The problem is, the new window is opening in a new tab, but doesnt get closed.

Comment: @Anu Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @guest271314: thanks for the pointer to the domain. When the URL is not accessible successfully, it wouldnt close the window. Once the proxy settings were changed, the new window closed properly (not sure why). Thanks again. I will check in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is working Fine, only thing is you need to give some time to see that window, alert boxes not required

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin;
function newWindow()
{
    newWin=window.open('http://www.google.co.in','_blank');
    setTimeout(function(){newWin.close()}, 5000);
}
</script>
<button onclick="newWindow()">open Window</button>
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer, though my problem lies with the proxy for the URL as @guest271314 pointed out.