# In SAS/HTML/javascript, how do you close a STP _webout html page immediately after it opens?

Tags: javascript, html, sas, sas-stored-process

From a form in a web page, I'm opening a stored process (STP) in a new window.

```
<form target="_blank" action="http://<UrlToMySTP>" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

that STP does someting and when it's done I need to close it's window.
So I tried to close it with javascript like this

```
data _null_;
    file _webout;
    put '<HTML>';
    put '   <HEAD>';
    put '   </HEAD>';
    put '   <BODY onLoad="window.close()">';
    put '   </BODY>';
    put '</HTML>';
    run;
```

but I get an error message that says:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it

I cannot find any solution for this.
Is is possible to circumvent the problem to get to the same result ?

Comment: Have you tried testing it with the same javascript that is independent of the STP?

Comment: @StuSztukowski I'm not sure to understand what you mean. (I did try to type `window.close()` in the console of the page when it's open but that gives the same error.)

Comment: If you use `window.open()` to open a pop up window, you get back a reference to the opened window. Using that reference, you can close the pop up window. This slightly different question/answer shows how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10702428/398606

Comment: @SunilD. the problem with that is that I don't know when the popup will be done doing it's job. Defining a timeout could either be too long or too short.

Comment: @stallingone with that reference to the pop up window, you are able to access properties and methods of the pop up window (see the "Return value" section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).  So for example, you could set a property in the pop up window when it's time to close, and then use `setTimeout` to poll the pop up from the main window and wait for that property to have the desired value. Not super elegant, but...

Answer (score 1):

You can try ajax query with `dataType: "jsonp"`. **Its can overcome CORS**.
STP must return json response, wrapped by name of js function, that wiil be executed in browser after ajax response.

## Example

### json_test.sas

```
 data _null_;
 file _WEBOUT;
 put "JSFunctionToAlertHTML({""Code"":0});";
 run;
```

### html_test.html

Must contain:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://servername:port/SASStoredProcess/do?_program=path%2Fjson_test&callback=?",
          dataType: "jsonp"
        });
```

*Make your attention to additional param `callback=`in url* .

And

```
  function JSFunctionToAlertHTML(json){
    //Your code
  }
```

You also if you use EG to cretae stored process, you must exclude Stored Process macros from STP settings and set result capabilities to Stream.

Comment: Lets start a discussion about this approach. When you set negative points  without argument, you do not benefit society SO

Comment: Interesting!  Can you clarify your point though about "exclude Stored Process macros from STP settings" ?  Not sure how this makes a difference..

Comment: Hello @AllanBowe ! Its necessary to avoid the next error `ERROR: File is in use, _WEBOUT .` . If its possibly do by another way, I would like to listen)) The screen of the settings is [here](http://imgur.com/lAqww7A)

Comment: aaah - I understand, it prevents the `%stpbegin` / `%stpend` macros from running.  Which yes, prevents the `_webout` fileref from being used.  This must be an EG option. I normally create my STPs programmatically!

Comment: @AllanBowe aw. I forgot that there is no this option in DI or MC. I will add it to my answer. Thank You!

Comment: `data _null_;
 file _WEBOUT;
 put "JSFunctionToAlertHTML({""Code"":0});";
 run;` is that javascript supposed to be executed ? (if so doesn't it need to be in `<html><script>` tags ?) I don't understant how that is suppose to work

Comment: @stallingone hello. This code will return the jsonp response. It must contain function, that you need to write in you code, and json-string as parameter of the function. Normal json ajax queries mostly can't get throw CORS policy.