# javascript window.open is not working in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I want link to be open in new window but when i click on write_review in IE it is opening in new tab.
I have checked for spaces in the arguments which are causing the problem. But no problem with that.

I have checked on URL :- [Javascript window.open is blocked by IE popup blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888964/javascript-window-open-is-blocked-by-ie-popup-blocker)

But its not working for me..

This is my working code in another browser.

```
    // Opening pop-up window for the write review
    jQuery('a#write_review').click(function() {
        var w = 1000;
        var h = 650;
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        var planid=$(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="data[PlanIdsel]"]').val();
        var providerid=$(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="data[ProviderIdsel]"]').val();
        var rep=$(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="data[Repsel]"]').val();
        var url = "<?php echo $this->webroot ?>"+"enrollments/write_rating/"+planid+"?Rep="+rep+"&providerId="+providerid;
        window.open(url, 'subWind', 'status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width='+w+', height='+h+', left='+left+', top='+top);
    });
```

Please guide me or correct me..

Comment: I have used "open_window" also in place of "subWind".. But it didn't work for me..

Comment: IE has some built in issues with window.open (i.e. it doesn't pass referrer url to another page). Check for window.open properties in google.

Comment: Any reason you tagged this question about JQuery with PHP?

Comment: I tried this and its working in IE too(with some other URL)

Comment: @MattLin I have given "about:blank" in place of url but it is not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459024/how-do-you-get-window-open-to-work-in-internet-explorer-7) How do you get window.open to work in internet explorer 7?

This is part of the security changes made in IE6. Now you can only call "window.open" from within a user-initiated event. For example, your code would work inside an element's onclick event. The "window.open" MSDN page says this

[link](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=51361)

Comment: Thanks.. +1 for your answer.. because you gave your time. And your answer is meaningful..

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#ID of your link").click(function(){
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 650;
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    var url = "your url";
    window.open(url, 'subWind', 'status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width='+w+', height='+h+', left='+left+', top='+top);
  });
});
```

this should work.

Comment: you can also use like  
    $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('a#hai').click(function(){});
    );

Comment: Thanks.. +1 for your answer.. because you gave your time